# I cannot contact people that have 'Liked' a page that has multiple URL parameters/arguments

Tags: url, parameters, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph, feed

Friends,

I am going crazy with this issue, I hope you have the answer for me as I have searched wide for this issue.  I have a WEB site that has implemented both the 'Like' button and the 'Comments' button.  The issue I'm having is actually two-fold:

**First**:

The usual 'Admin Page' link that goes beside the 'Like' button once the Admin (me) has liked the page is not always present... I can't figure why, because they are exactly the same PHP pages with different info filled from the DB, but they have identical structure.  So I don't understand why:

- www.rafaelpolit.com/inicio/index.php?sid=14&gim=10

Shows me the Admin Page link, while

- www.rafaelpolit.com/inicio/index.php?sid=14&gim=183

Doesn't.
Any ideas?

**Second**:

The above problem would not be much of an issue if the procedure described on the Open Graph Protocol page (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/#publishing) under Publishing would actually work!  Here's the actual problem:

- My page uses two parameters in the URL to define the page content: one is the section, the other is the image ID.

My other pages that use a single URL attribute, work fine!!! So, if I access (I am using the graph for simplified purposes):

- https://graph.facebook.com/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.rafaelpolit.com%2Finicio%2Findex.php%3Fsid%3D106

It correctly shows:

```
{
   "id": "117419061672096",
   "name": "Rafael P\u00f3lit - Macro y Objetos",
   "picture": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/188186_117419061672096_2606222_s.jpg",
   "link": "http://www.rafaelpolit.com/inicio/index.php?sid=106",
   "likes": 2,
   "category": "Unknown",
   "website": "http://www.rafaelpolit.com/inicio/index.php?sid=106",
   "description": "-",
   "can_post": true
}
```

But if I access the graph for one of the URLs with multiple arguments, like:

- https://graph.facebook.com/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.rafaelpolit.com%2Finicio%2Findex.php%3Fsid%3D14%26gim%3D10

It truncates the second argument and shows:

```
{
   "id": "http://www.rafaelpolit.com/inicio/index.php?sid=14"
}
```

As you can see if you enter this though:

- graph.facebook.com/159684077425429

The Facebook page is actually correctly working!!! :( Is there a way to actually know a Page_ID if I cannot access the page from any place other than my own site?

So, to sum up my issue:

- For some pages I don't get the Admin Page link
- For those pages, I have no way of knowing the Page_id
- The graph options are not working for pages that have multiple URL arguments/parameters
- In the exact same fashion, the *https://graph.facebook.com/feed* option does not send messages to the people that have 'liked' a page for those pages that have multiple URL parameters, it works fine for those with single parameter.

How do I access the information of a page with two or more parameters?

My final goal is to make something like this actually WORK!:

```
<?php
$ogurl = urlencode("http://www.rafaelpolit.com/inicio/index.php?sid=14&gim=10");
define("FACEBOOK_APP_ID", "15xxxx84127xxxx");
define("FACEBOOK_SECRET", "xxxx5391830xxxx744b171f0d4b5xxxx");

$mymessage = "Thank you for 'Liking' my Picture.";

$access_token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token"; 
$parameters = "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=" . FACEBOOK_APP_ID .
    "&client_secret=" . FACEBOOK_SECRET;
$access_token = file_get_contents($access_token_url . "?" . $parameters);

$apprequest_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/feed";
$parameters = "?" . $access_token . "&message=" .
    urlencode($mymessage) . "&id=" . $ogurl . "&method=post";
$myurl = $apprequest_url . $parameters;

$result = file_get_contents($myurl);

// output the post id
echo "post_id" . $result;
?>
```

I repeat:  This works FINE! if I use the URL of pages with a single URL parameter, it does NOT work if I use URL of pages with multiple parameters.

Any insight?  This is a complex issue and I am not a native English speaker, so forgive the extension and any confusion.  I appreciate all and every help you may provide!

Thanks a lot,

Rafael Pólit.

ps. Please forgive the non-working links, since I'm new only two of them could actually be links. Most work as copy paste links though, except the graph link which needs https:// in the beginning.  Thanks for understanding.

---

**Edit 1:**

In response to @Abby 's comment bellow, this is the code I'm using (hopefully formatted instead of the responses in my comments) to insert the button:

```
<div class="fb_cont ui-corner-all" style="width:706px">
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({appId: '154581841273133', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
  };
  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol +
      '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());
//]]>
</script>
<div class="fb_cont_int" style="padding:5px;">
    <div class="fb_likeDiv" style="width:240px;">
        <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.rafaelpolit.com/inicio/index.php?sid=14&amp;gim=183" data-send="false" data-width="240" data-show-faces="true" data-colorscheme="dark" data-font="tahoma"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="fb_commentDiv" style="width:446px;">

        <div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://www.rafaelpolit.com/inicio/index.php?sid=14&amp;gim=183" data-num-posts="4" data-width="446" data-colorscheme="dark"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="dummy"><!-- --></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Thanks again @Abby for looking into my issue.

---

Comment: for your first problem - the admin pages - what code have you used for the like button? The first issue might be the same as your second issue if you have those parameters in there.

Comment: @Abby , Thanks for the reply!  I doubt it since there is an apparent random inconsistency: it sometimes work and others doesn't!  But, of course, that may very well be the problem.  Here is the like button's code:

Comment: `<div class="fb_cont ui-corner-all" style="width:706px">
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({appId: '154581841273133', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
  };
  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol +
      '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());
//]]>
</script>`

Comment: `<div class="fb_cont_int" style="padding:5px;">
 <div class="fb_likeDiv" style="width:240px;">
     <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.rafaelpolit.com/inicio/index.php?sid=14&amp;gim=183" data-send="false" data-width="240" data-show-faces="true" data-colorscheme="dark" data-font="tahoma"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="fb_commentDiv" style="width:446px;">
     <div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://www.rafaelpolit.com/inicio/index.php?sid=14&amp;gim=183" data-num-posts="4" data-width="446" data-colorscheme="dark"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>`

Comment: @Abby, very sorry about the formatting above, still learning.

Comment: @Abby, I have added the code into the main question for better reading in the section named **Edit 1**.  Thanks.